# Pick from an intersection type? (TS)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am quite new to TS and wrote a pick function but finding it difficult to pick from an intersection type:

```
type PaletteType = {
   black: string,
   white: string
}

type ColorType = {
   primaryColor: string,
   labelText: string,
}

type Props = {
   ...,
   backgroundColor: keyof ColorType | keyof PaletteType // (or would keyof (ColorType & PaletteType) would be better?
}

// Some general pick funtion
function pick<T extends { [key: string]: any }, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key?: K) {
    if (key) { return object[key] }
    return undefined
}

pick(Colors, props.backgroundColor) // error -> black | white not assignable to Colors
```

I am quite sure my 'solution' is kinda wrong:

```
backgroundColor: pick(Palette as typeof Palette & typeof Color, props.bg) || pick(Color as typeof Palette & typeof Color, props.bg),
```

Comment: If `pick` is picking from `Colors` then it is not valid to pass in a key of `PalletType` .. not sure what a good way to express this would be

Comment: Yeah :/ not sure either. I want to be able to pick from either Palette or Color. (maybe of course I could also merge the Palette and the Colors what would make more sense in a typed langauge...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding these declarations to make the code compile:

```
declare const Colors: ColorType;
declare const Palette: PaletteType;
declare const props: Props;
```

In order to make your call to `pick()` type safe you can either merge `Colors` and `Palette` via something like object spread:

```
pick({ ...Colors, ...Palette }, props.backgroundColor); // okay
```

That works because `{...Colors, ...Palette}` is seen to be of type `ColorType & PaletteType`, whose keys are `keyof ColorType | keyof PaletteType`.

Or, you can make a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to narrow `props.backgroundColor` to either `keyof ColorType` or `keyof PaletteType` before calling `pick()`:

```
const hasKey = <T extends object>(obj: T, key: keyof any): key is keyof T => key in obj;

hasKey(Colors, props.backgroundColor) ? 
  pick(Colors, props.backgroundColor) : 
  pick(Palette, props.backgroundColor); // okay
```

The former is probably neater.

By the way, I'm not sure what `pick(o,k)` buys you over just `o[k]`, but that's up to you I guess.

Hope that helps; good luck!